# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: slick.driver.JdbcProfile$API.streamableQueryActionExtensionMethods

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to do a normal

"select" using db.run(tableQ.result) being

protected val tableQ: TableQuery[T] 
by the examples it looks like I'm doing it ok, but I get the error: play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: slick.driver.JdbcProfile$

I located the reason has to being this line of code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: slick.driver.JdbcProfile$API.streamableQueryActionExtensionMethods(Lslick/lifted/Query;)Lslick/profile/BasicActionComp$$$$6aa48549c0a7603df1fa229cf7177493$$$$sionMethodsImpl;
        at models.daos.BaseDAO.getAll(BaseDAO.scala:62)
        at controllers.CategoryController$$anonfun$list$1.apply(CategoryController.scala:28)

def getAll : Future[Seq[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.result)
  }
```

BaseDAO.scala

```
package models.daos

import models.entities.{Supplier, BaseEntity, Category, Product}
import models.persistence.SlickTables
import models.persistence.SlickTables.{SuppliersTable, BaseTable, CategoriesTable, ProductsTable}
import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfig}
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.lifted.{CanBeQueryCondition}
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

trait AbstractBaseDAO[T,A] {
  def insert(row : A): Future[Long]
  def insert(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Seq[Long]]
  def update(row : A): Future[Int]
  def update(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Unit]
  def findById(id : Long): Future[Option[A]]
  def findByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f: (T) => C): Future[Seq[A]]
  def deleteById(id : Long): Future[Int]
  def deleteById(ids : Seq[Long]): Future[Int]
  def deleteByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f:  (T) => C): Future[Int]
  def getAll() : Future[Seq[A]]
}


abstract class BaseDAO[T <: BaseTable[A], A <: BaseEntity]() extends AbstractBaseDAO[T,A] with HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {
  protected lazy val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  protected val tableQ: TableQuery[T]

  def insert(row : A): Future[Long] ={
    insert(Seq(row)).map(_.head)
  }

  def insert(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Seq[Long]] ={
    db.run(tableQ returning tableQ.map(_.id) ++= rows.filter(_.isValid))
  }

  def update(row : A): Future[Int] = {
    if (row.isValid)
      db.run(tableQ.filter(_.id === row.id).update(row))
    else
      Future{0}
  }

  def update(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Unit] = {
    db.run(DBIO.seq((rows.filter(_.isValid).map(r => tableQ.filter(_.id === r.id).update(r))): _*))
  }

  def findById(id : Long): Future[Option[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
  }

  def findByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f: (T) => C): Future[Seq[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.withFilter(f).result)
  }

  def getAll : Future[Seq[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.result)
  }

  def deleteById(id : Long): Future[Int] = {
    deleteById(Seq(id))
  }

  def deleteById(ids : Seq[Long]): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(tableQ.filter(_.id.inSet(ids)).delete)
  }

  def deleteByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f:  (T) => C): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(tableQ.withFilter(f).delete)
  }

}
```

build.sbt

```
version := "0.0.1"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1",
  evolutions,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.191",
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0-RC1" % Test
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Compiling using ./activator run

Comment: how are you compiing / building your code? this looks like a classpath issue

Comment: or maybe using `Slick` version compiled for different `Scala` version?

Comment: I've made an edit so it shows my build.sbt and I'm using activator run to compile the code, my target is a link to /tmp/project-target because of a bug related with using encryptfs in linux

Comment: I had a local.sbt file in ~/.sbt/0.13/local.sbt that had a line stating to scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xmax-classfile-name","78") and this was causing the issue, I forgot to remove it after solving a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this (although I am not sure which Play version you are using) ?

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0"
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
)
```

Comment: No go. This was working well before I ran into a issue of file name to long, And then I also changed the routes file in playframework.

Comment: which play version are you using?

Comment: I upgraded to play-slick 2.0.0 witch comes with slick 3.1 and play 2.5.0

Comment: Ok, does it mean that problem disappeared already (your comment about changes in `sbt`) ?

Comment: Yes. The problem was that entry I had in local.sbt to reduce the class file name. Thank you for your help.